scipy.special.eval_hermite with complex argument
Does the scipy.special eval_hermite function only support real arguments? From the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.eval_hermite.html), I assumed complex would work fine and I also don't see any programmatic reason why it should not. However, I get the following error:
scipy.special.eval_hermite(4, 1.j)
# output: TypeError: ufunc 'eval_hermite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Does anyone know why this is? Or how to work around it?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2086044

It's a compiled ufunc so code isn't readily available (but may be dug out from github).  The error indicates that it expects x to be a real float.  I don't see anything in the docs to support your assumption.

It seems that the following numpy class works for complex-valued inputs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.hermite.Hermite.html#numpy.polynomial.hermite.Hermite
